# Forwarding of root URL only?

Tags: linux, domain, htaccess

I have a domain and I would like and visits to the root of the domain only to be forwarded.
For example:

www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/holding

However

www.domain.com/home
www.domain.com/index.php
www.domain.com/*

Will all still go to those locations.
I believe this is a .htaccess modification, however I do not know how to do this.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Why don't you add a simple piece of JS to a html file at domain.com

Comment: Going to the root will load up index.html first and index.php if there is no HTML.  I already have an index.html file there that I require access to, but only want access if the user specifies it in the URL field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [mod_rewrite's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /holding [NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
Redirect / /holding
```

to you .htaccess or your Apache site configuration.